# Backbone save without set on callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a drag&drop functionality in my web app. As the user releases the mouse after a drag&drop, the position of the object is saved to the server using Backbone's save() method on the model. When the server responds, it triggers a set() on the model with the returned properties. However, in the time the server was processing the request, the user might already have again dragged the object to a different position. This causes problems as the response from the server will now override the settings of the object in the browser.

Is there a way to prevent Backbone from doing the set() after it gets the response from the server after the save()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use the following solution:

Override the default parse method of a model:

```
Backbone.Model.prototype.parse = function(resp, options) {
    if(options.parse)
        return resp;
};
```

Now, you can use the save method with the property 'parse' set to false to prevent the ajax response to override your current values:

```
MyModel.save({}, { parse: false });
```

Answer (score 3):

Had similar use case while doing a system before albeit that was more trouble hence we needed to really override the models `set()` function. Although for this case a couple of relatively easier ways are available.

You can override the model [parse()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) function. Or you can call an `abort()` on the  jqXHR object returned by the `save()` call.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: But that would impact all save operations right? Because I don't want to break the functionality on other save operations.

Comment: Unless you override `model.save`, calling `abort` on success callback is too late the backbone own callback will have been executed hence your model already set with server attributes. Regarding OP original question… unfortunately no, there is no such option. However, the easiest way to deal with this is writing your own server synchronisation function and use that function instead of `model.save`. You can also override `save` just for that particular model too.

Comment: IMHO a more concrete solution would probably involve creating some sort of update timestamp or version counter and within your `model.validate` or `model.parse` you can do something with the timestamp or counter.

Comment: you can override the `parse()` function on just a specific model.

Comment: calling the `abort` on  a success call back, i agree, would be too late. what i was implying was to store the `jqXHR` object on the model, when `dragenter` event is triggered on the corresponding view, call an custom function on the model that then triggers the `jqXHR.abort()`

Answer (score 2):

Look into the "wait" option, by default it should be set to false which means your model fields should be set immediately after calling save(). You can set {wait:true} to make backbone wait for the server reply before setting the updated model field values.

From your described behavior, it sounds like wait option is set to true in your application.

Further details: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save

One other important thing to remember is backbone only sets the subset of updated fields you return from the called webservice, so if you don't return any none will be set.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I don't have the wait option set to true. The thing is that Backbone will always use the set method after server response if the returned parameters are different then the ones currently on the model.

Answer (score 2):

`Model.save` will call `Model.parse` on the data received with the same `options` argument before actually setting it.

You could call `Model.save` with a custom flag (let's say `position: true`) indicating that `Model.parse` can discard what the server returns.

For example, assuming your coordinates are `x` and `y`

```
var M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(data, options)  {
        if (options && options.position)
            data = _.omit(data, 'x', 'y');

        return data;
    }
});

var m = new M();
m.save({x: 10, y:10}, {position: true});
m.save({x: 20, y:20}, {position: true});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/YwC7q/

Comment: This looks like a great idea. I'm actually wondering why this isn't implemented in Backbone already. I would expect a more generally named option parameter like 'parse' where you can set properties that should be ignored on server response.

Comment: Looking closer at the save method of Backbone, I can see that it looks at a property 'parse' and passes this property forward to the default parse method. In that parse method it does nothing with that property. If I change that to check if options.parse is true, I can use that property to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have used approach to freeze UI until ajax request is performed. We've added two additional events freeze/unfreeze to the model that triggered before save and after receiving answer from the sever.

Comment: That's a horrible user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the '.sync()' method. Backbone.save() delegates to Backbone.sync() after overriding the success callback that you pass in. That is where the model update is coming from.

From the source of the Backbone.save() method:

```
var success = options.success;
  options.success = function(resp) {
    // Ensure attributes are restored during synchronous saves.
    model.attributes = attributes;
    var serverAttrs = model.parse(resp, options);
    if (options.wait) serverAttrs = _.extend(attrs || {}, serverAttrs);
    if (_.isObject(serverAttrs) && !model.set(serverAttrs, options)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (success) success(model, resp, options);
    model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
  };
  wrapError(this, options);

  method = this.isNew() ? 'create' : (options.patch ? 'patch' : 'update');
  if (method === 'patch') options.attrs = attrs;
  xhr = this.sync(method, this, options);
```

You could pass a custom option when you call '.save()', then look for that option and override options.success callback in '.sync()'. Something like this, maybe?

```
MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function (method, context, options) {
        if (options.skipUpdateOnResponse) {
            options.success = myCusomSuccessFunction;
        }
    }
});

myModel = new MyModel();

myModel.save({...}, {skipUpdateOnResponse: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

What properties is the server responding with? The default success callback that Backbone uses does this:

```
if (_.isObject(serverAttrs) && !model.set(serverAttrs, options)) { ... }
```

Following this logic, if your server doesn't return an object, `set` should not be called on your model.

Alternatively, if you modify your server response so that it doesn't return the position info that gets passed in (which is the root cause of your problem, and without understanding your requirements, also seems a bit redundant) those properties shouldn't get overridden when `set` is called.

Barring these options, overriding `sync` as @Uselessinfo suggests or putting some trickery in `parse` are probably your next best bets.

Comment: Unfortunately if you return empty body for JSON requests, it will be treated as invalid response and will trigger error callback. Returning empty JSON object (`{}`) will reset the model to empty. So those two are not the option...

Comment: Well I guess you could return the rest of the model (or just the id property), so the JSON is not invalid

Comment: @j03w - Returning an empty JSON will not reset the model. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccamarat/7UV9S/. You're correct about the empty response.

Comment: hmm interesting, thank for clarifying that I was on the wrong impression then. I used to return empty json and somehow my models became empty. I might have done something wrong… have to go back and check my code I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use the validate method on the model:

```
validate: function(attrs) {
    var errors = [];
    if (attrs.position !== this.get('position')) {
        errors.push('Outdated info!');
    }
    return _.any(errors) ? errors : null;
}
```

This way you can compare the server response with the existing data in the model. If the server response is different from the data in the model, return errors and the `set` method will not get called. This may require `wait: true` in the `save` method options. With this approach i think you should set the position on the model before doing the actual save.

> validate is called before save, but can also be called before set if {validate:true}

Answer (score 0):

Backbone save success callback:

```
  options.success = function(resp, status, xhr) {
    done = true;
    var serverAttrs = model.parse(resp, xhr);
    if (options.wait) serverAttrs = _.extend(attrs || {}, serverAttrs);
    if (!model.set(serverAttrs, options)) return false;
    if (success) success(model, resp, options);
    model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
  };
```

So it calls set allways before trigger 'sync' called and before user success function called.
There is no way to prevent Backbone of doing set, but there is a way to solve your problem.
You can override 'set' function in your model like this way:

```
set: function() {
  if (this.skipSetOperation()) return false;
  return Backbone.Model.prototype.set.apply(this, arguments);
},

skipSetOperation: function() {
  //this function should return stage - can model set attributes in this moment or not
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Write another function for your save, and instead of using save use your function.

in model:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     savePosition: function(){
           var model = this;    
           $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                cache: false,
                dataType : 'json',
                contentType : 'application/json',
                data:JSON.stringify(data),
                url : "urlToSave",
                success:function(responseText,statusText){
                    model.trigger('saved',responseText);
                },
                error : function(error, dataObj, xhr) {
                                        alert('Error');
                }
      });    
     }
}
```

here in view bind method of saved, and trigger the method after save.

```
this.model.on('saved',function(){
   // do call back stuff
});
this.model.savePosition({data:{...}});
```